# jQuery change aria-expanded attribute depending on its value

Tags: jquery, attr, wai-aria

I have an item that I want to change aria-expanded attribute depending on the current state.

It changes OK to true, but for some reason doesn't change to false on the second click:

html

```
 <li aria-expanded=false>hey</li>
```

jQuery

```
$("li").on("click", function(e) {
     var menuItem = $(e.currentTarget);

     if (menuItem.attr("aria-expanded") == true) {
          $(this).attr("aria-expanded", false);
     } else {
          $(this).attr("aria-expanded", true);
     }
     return false;
});
```

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/jLYRpg

Answer (score 3, accepted):

HTML attributes are strings, so you should be using the string version of `true` and `false`.

```js
$(function () { 
    $('li').on('click', function (e) {
        var menuItem = $( e.currentTarget );

        if (menuItem.attr( 'aria-expanded') === 'true') {
            $(this).attr( 'aria-expanded', 'false');
        } else {
            $(this).attr( 'aria-expanded', 'true');
        }
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<li aria-expanded="false">hey</li>
```

Or, you could remove the `if` statement entirely

```
$(this).attr( 'aria-expanded', menuItem.attr('aria-expanded') === 'true' ? false : true);
```

Or use the inverse

```
let expanded = menuItem.attr('aria-expanded') === 'true'
$(this).attr('aria-expanded', !!expanded)
```